# Getting the error, "Internal error: The Interpreter has already been closed." after calling dispose() to free up memory

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm using flutter platform channels to use `tflite` in java. The interpreters are memory heavy so when I exit the current screen/page I dispose the interpreters, but when I navigate back to the page I get the error:

> E/flutter ( 7960): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Internal error: The
> Interpreter has already been closed., null,
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: The Interpreter has
> already been closed.

Here is a minimal example of what I am doing in flutter

```
class StyleTransfer extends StatefulWidget {
  final selectedImage;

  const StyleTransfer({
    Key key,
    this.selectedImage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StyleTransferState createState() => _StyleTransferState();
}

    class _StyleTransferState extends State<StyleTransfer> {
      static const platform = const MethodChannel("com.name.package/tflite_java");
    
    
      @override
      Future<void> dispose() async{
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async{
          await platform.invokeMethod("DisposeInterpreter").then((value) => print(value));
        });
    
        super.dispose();
      }
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
      ...
      }
    }
```

and this is the dispose function in java

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.name.package/tflite_java";
    protected Interpreter predictInterpreter;
    protected Interpreter transformInterpreter;
    protected Interpreter.Options interpreterOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

    private ImageSegmenter imageSegmenter;

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        try {
            interpreterOptions.setNumThreads(4);
            predictInterpreter = new Interpreter(loadModelFile("prediction_1.tflite"), interpreterOptions);
            transformInterpreter = new Interpreter(loadModelFile("transfer_1.tflite"), interpreterOptions);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
            if (call.method.equals("StylePredict")){

                // irrelevant code removed for minimal example;
            }
            else if (call.method.equals("DisposeInterpreter")){
                String response = DisposeInterpreter();
                result.success(response);
            }
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
        });
    }

    

    private String DisposeInterpreter() {
        predictInterpreter.close();
        transformInterpreter.close();
        return "All Models closed";
    }
}
```

When I press back from the `StyleTransfer` page, I get the `All Models closed` message, so that is working, but when I go back to this page with a new image I get the above error:

> E/MethodChannel#com.name.package/tflite_java( 7960): Failed to handle
> method call E/MethodChannel#com.name.package/tflite_java( 7960):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: The Interpreter has
> already been closed.